# iPhone Dev Objective-C - Object is being retained and I don't know where

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, release, retain

I'm creating an iPad game that has a viewController that loads in its view from a nib file. The view has a bunch of buttons in it, which I linked up to UIButton * variables via interface builder (so each button is linked to a different variable). I checked the retain count right after they nib was loaded on one of the buttons (using my first button variable, b1) and it gives me a value of 2. Can anyone explain why it's 2? What are the two things that are retaining it right after the nib loads?

And now I'm even more confused because in my dealloc function, I released each of the button variables individually, and checked the retain count for one of them after and it's STILL 2! It should at least have gone down to 1, shouldn't it have? Should I release it several times in my dealloc function? If so, how many?

Thanks

Comment: Are you linking them to retained properties?

Comment: Try profiling using instruments. The memory leak checker should show you where it's being retained.

Comment: @shawnwall I'm not linking them to retained properties. I figured it would make no difference since I never explicitly set the button variables (thus a setter is not needed)     @Maz thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 7):

Don't look at retain count.

Seriously.

Things other than you retain your stuff. Those numbers will move around underneath you for reasons that appear to make no sense, and then you'll come back here and post bewildered questions.

Just make sure your retains and releases balance. That's your only job.

Comment: On an iOS device it is even more important, due to the limited memory, that all memory is being used efficiently. If there is a failure, the end user doesn't care if it was you or Apple that failed, they'll just blame you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One follow-up question: does it matter if I have my IBOulets set as properties if I never explicitly set or get them? (As in the IBOutlet button variables I connected up to the buttons in the nib file)? And should I release all those button variables at the end, even though I never explicitly retained them (they were set up via interface builder)?

Comment: @Tim - When your view loads, they'll be retained (assuming you used the 'retain' setter semantic in your property declarations). So you need to release them.

Comment: @Dan Ray - I didn't actually make the button IBOutlets properties, I just declared them as variables in my header. Does this mean I don't have to worry about releasing them? (I never explicitly set any of them either).

Comment: @Tim - No, it means you haven't retained them, and that's dangerous. Definitely want to make them properties, using the 'retain' setter semantic, and explicitly release them in `-dealloc`.

Comment: @Dan Ray - OK thanks. Just so I have a full understanding, does this mean that the setter methods (which will retain them if the property so specifies) for my IBOutlets are implicitly called when the nib file loads?

Comment: Provided they're wired up properly in IB, yes. That's what that wiring IS--it's a connection between the nib element and the property (getter/setter) code.

Answer (score 1):

If your IBOutlet properties are retained then you would have 1 retain there and another when the button gets added to the super view...

As Dan Ray says though, you shouldn't really worry about the retainCount...